# Error in adding subnet while creating WAFV2 application gateway in azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, subnet, azure-application-gateway, azure-waf

While adding subnet for creating a WAFV2 application gateway in azure, I tried to use the subnet used in WAFV1 gateway.
But it is showing an error "Subnet does not support application gateway tier".

Answer (score 2):

In your virtual network, an application gateway is a dedicated deployment. The application gateway requires its own subnet within your virtual network.
In a subnet, you can have many instances of the same application gateway deployment.
Both v2 and v1 Application Gateway SKUs cannot be supported by the same subnet.
please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-infrastructure#:%7E:text=user%20defined%20routes.-,Virtual%20network%20and%20dedicated%20subnet,gateway%20deployment%20in%20a%20subnet.).